# What was this SciFi story?

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I have read a SciFi book a while ago, and would like to find the author.

The book featured two robots, who were seeking to find their owner so they could give him some sort of secret plan.

The owner, who resembled some sort of SciFi samurai, complete with futuristic sword, then had to deal with some whiny annoying farmer, and deliver the secret plan to a beautiful princess.

I think there were some space battles in the end.

Comment: troll, I think.

Comment: [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1675/2565)

Comment: @Ward - care to prove the **malicious intent**, which is what distinguishes a troll from a clever April 1st joke? +1.

Comment: If it wasn't asked on April 1, would we want it on the site?  When it's no longer April 1, will it still be visible?

Comment: dlanod - I think it would be fine even outside April 1. The only thing April 1 does is makes it extra double absolutely obvious that it wasn't asked as a troll. As per Kevin's answer to Meta discussion, the question stands on merit as fullly ontopic.

Answer (score 9):

OK, I'll bite.

Caelumviator seems to sound very Latin...

Google Translate gives us: Caelum=Sky; Viator=Traveler.

If that wasn't a Latin translation of "Skywalker", I'm going to eat my honorary SciFi.SE Latin Google badge (Hint to SE team: I want that badge!)

---

Since the actual details of the plot in the question seem to match (2 robots, R2-D2 and C-3PO seek their owner, Obi-Wan Kenobi, to deliver the Death Star plans to him so he can send them to rebels on Aldaraan - and obviously there is a big space battle in the end), the book you read must have been [novelization](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV%3a_A_New_Hope_%28novel%29) of none other than "Star Wars":

> The Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope novelization, originally entitled Star Wars: From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker, was the official novel adaptation of the film Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope, published in 1976 by Ballantine Books. **It was ghostwritten by Alan Dean Foster, but credited to George Lucas.**

The actual answer to your question (who was the author) is bolded by me above

---

An additional factor confirming this was, of course, the mention of the owner being a Samurai - it is a well known fact that George Lucas acknowledged a strong [influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_Fortress#Influence) of "Hidden Fortress", one of the classic Samurai movies, on "Star Wars: A New Hope".

Comment: As if you need any more rep. :)

Comment: @KyleJones - hey it's not my fault I'm a brilliant^H^H^H^H^H^H lucky Latin linguist^H^H^H^H^H^H a guy with Google Translate

Comment: @DVK so you're a "bri lucky Latin li a guy with Google Translate"? ;)

Comment: @dlanod - I haz can countz!